# stringByAppendingString doesn't return modified string

Tags: swift

This is what I am trying in a playground file. The result I want is the second `println` result using `stringByAppendingString`. Isn't `stringByAppendingString` is supposed to return modified string? What am I doing wrong here?

```
var reportSummary:String = "Total: \t\t300.00"
reportSummary.stringByAppendingString("Net: \t\t200.00")
println(reportSummary)
// Total:    300.00


var reportSum = "Total: \t300.00\n"
var netSum = "Net: \t\t200.00\n"
var sum = reportSum + netSum
println(sum)
// Total:    300.00
// Net:      200.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stringByAppendingString` message creates and returns a new `String`. It doesn't modify the receiver (the original `String`).

If you want to use the combined `String`, you need to do something with the return value. The code you posted ignores the return value. You can, for example, store the returned `String` in your `reportSummary` variable like this:

```
var reportSummary:String = "Total: \t\t300.00"
reportSummary = reportSummary.stringByAppendingString("\nnNet: \t\t200.00")
println(reportSummary)
```

You might as well use the `+=` operator, though:

```
var reportSummary = "Total: \t\t300.00"
reportSummary += "\nNet: \t\t200.00"
println(reportSummary)
```

Or you can use the `extend` method:

```
var reportSummary = "Total: \t\t300.00"
reportSummary.extend("\nNet: \t\t200.00")
println(reportSummary)
```

Or you can explicitly use the Foundation type `NSMutableString`:

```
let reportSummary: NSMutableString = "Total: \t\t300.00"
reportSummary.appendString("\nNet: \t\t200.00")
println(reportSummary)
```

Comment: “In fact, in Swift, objects of type String cannot be modified. They are immutable.” This is not true.